# RFID locating system android application

Tags: android, rfid

I am trying to develop an android mobile app to find lost objects using the RFID technology. After much research I found that insted of needing an RFID reader, I would need an RFID radar. What's the difference between them?

What does my app need to have to locate the tags in particular?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is as follows:

- NFC readers (or HF RFID readers) do have  a range up to half a meter to a meter, the NFC readers in smartphones or tablets usually up to a maximum of 5 to 10 cm
- UHF RFID readers read tags up to 10 meters, as it is a different technology compared to HF RFID/NFC
- RFID radars are UHF RFID readers with the additional capability to estimate the location/distance/direction of UHF RFID tags